# About sending time to infinity in a slightly imaginary direction in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum, regularization, wick-rotation

I am going through the Peskin and Schroeder QFT book. While proving the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem) in chapter 4 of their book, the authors started with the equation
\begin{equation}
e^{-iHT}|0\rangle = e^{-iE_{0}T}| \Omega\rangle \langle \Omega | 0 \rangle + \sum_{n\ne0}e^{-iE_{n}T}| n\rangle \langle n | 0 \rangle.\tag{p.86}
\end{equation}
And argued that for all the $n\ne 0$ terms die out in the limit time $T$ send to $\infty$ in a **slightly imaginary direction**: $T \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)$. Which yields equation (4.27) namely

\begin{equation}
| \Omega \rangle = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)}\frac{e^{-iHT}|0\rangle}{e^{-iE_{0}T}\langle \Omega | 0 \rangle}.\tag{4.27}
\end{equation}
I am confused about sending the time $T$ to $\infty$ in a **slightly imaginary direction**: $T \rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)$. Is this something mathematically rigorous or just a purely mathematical artifact? I hope someone can enlighten me making this point clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:  The adiabatic cutoff of interactions in the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem) is heuristically equivalent to an  $i\epsilon$ prescription. Both serve as a regularization.

In more details: We can either$^1$

1. adiabatically switch on/off interactions in the Hamiltonian [1]
   $$\hat{H}_{S}(t)~=~\hat{H}_0+e^{-\epsilon |t|}\hat{V}_S;$$
2. or use an $i\epsilon$ prescription in the complex time plane [2]
   $${}_H\langle\Psi_+|~~\propto~~{}_{H_0}\langle\Psi_0|\hat{U}_I(\infty(1\!-\!i\epsilon),0)$$
   and
   $$\Psi_-\rangle_H~~\propto~~\hat{U}_I(0,-\infty(1\!-\!i\epsilon)) |\Psi_0\rangle_{H_0}$$
   using a Hamiltonian
   $$\hat{H}_{S}~=~\hat{H}_0+\hat{V}_S$$
   without explicit time dependence;
3. or apply an $i\epsilon$ prescription
   $$\hat{H}_{S}\to \hat{H}_{S}-i\epsilon$$
   to the Hamiltonian itself [3].

The $i\epsilon$ prescription endows wildly oscillatory expressions with an exponentially decaying regularization.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137171/2451) related Phys.SE post.

References:

1. A.L. Fetter & J.D. Walecka, *Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems,* 2003; p. 61-64.
2. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; p. 86-87.
3. The third approach is closely related to the [Lippmann-Schwinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation).

--

$^1$The subscripts $S$, $H$ and $I$ stand for the [Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), [Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) and [interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) picture, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 1. Does the $i\epsilon$ prescription have anything to do with the notion of the Cauchy Principal Value integral in complex analysis? 2. I thought it was introduced so that one can make sense of divergent integrals in QFT.

Comment: Hi Valac. 1. Not directly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the reason for such writing is to make the numerator and denominator have a definite limit at $t \rightarrow \infty$, this shift leads to exponential decay of them, so they both approach zero, whereas without such a prescription both parts are poor-defined stuff like $\sin \infty$. There seems to be no physical meaning, rather a matter of convenience, some kind of regularization.